# How to fix an StackOverflow Error in Searching and Filtering with Spring Data Jpa with multi relational Data Tables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

This is the entity that I want to apply filtering to. It has a `ManyToOne` relationship with `x` entity.

```java
public class BaseEntity {


    private String identifier;

    
    private String type;


    private String model;


    private Integer capacity;


    private Integer point;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "x_id")
    private XEntity x;

// getter, setters and constructors...

}
```

And this is the entity which has `OneToMany` relationship with base entity is also has.

```java
public class XEntity {


    private String identifier;


    private String code;


    private String name;


    private String country;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "x",cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private Set<BaseEntity> bases;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "x",cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private Set<YEntity> y;

    // getter, setters and constructors...

}
```

When I tried to code filtering with Spring Data JPA, a `StackOverflowError` has occured on mapping the `y` object in an `x` object.

MY ONLY PROBLEM IS:
I mapped join columns as their id columns in domain and dto layers and expect not to get the error, but it occurred.

How do I solve the problem?

[This is my debug console when I launch the search request on the controller, it is showing `x` entity which tries mapping to `y` entity inside the object.]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaiVv.png

Comment: Welcome to SO. I've submitted an edit request to your post as there's not need to use the maximum font size for your paragraph. Also, it might be hard to help you without knowing at least the code you use to apply the filtering.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea for the problem?

Comment: Do you use Lombok? How do you do the mapping from Entity to DTO?

Comment: Yes, i use Lombok. I use mappers to map Entity to Domain and Domain to DTO.

Comment: @KeremShtyn as Simon and I said, it's quite difficult to help you without your mapping and/or filtering code...

Comment: Actually I solved the problem but reason of the problem was not about mapping or filtering. Problem is about relations and toString.Firstly, I added @JsonIgnore annotation to OneToMany relations. Then, toString excludes should have applied to Entity.After that, my problem solved and application launched with zero defect.